# Redirect one IP address to another from windows 7

Tags: windows, redirect, nat

I have several programs running on a local server, attacking a database hosted on another server but within the same private network.

The problem arises because I am going to move that database to a cloud service.

And the programs have defined the connection to the database by IP, that is, they access by 192.168.1.5\sqlexpress. I have installed the instance in the cloud with the same name but of course the IP will be a public IP of the server.

Can I redirect the IP 192.168.1.5 to the public IP of my cloud server (from the windows itself in which it runs, because I can't touch the network infrastructure) to avoid touching the .exe programs?

Comment: What does your question have to do with VBA?

Comment: Only know about working solutions for redirecting by port. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have to set up a VPN to connect to the cloud

Make sure your Cloud SQL instance has an public IP address, enable the outside-visible IP address of your workstation

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-cloud-shell#work